# CMake: The C compiler identification is unknown

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I am trying to build a project by cmake 2.8.12 with visual studio 10 in 32bit architecture. But I am getting these error and cmake is unable to create the project. Can anyone please suggest me a solution. Thanks.

This is the error showing in cmake-gui window:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:446 (execute_process):
  execute_process given COMMAND argument with no value.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:48 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_VENDOR)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:131 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:446 (execute_process):
  execute_process given COMMAND argument with no value.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:48 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_VENDOR)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:127 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


The CXX compiler identification is unknown
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this @Tonmoy? Running into this myself. Looks like a cmake bug.

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove Cmake cache
2. Start `Visual Studio 10 (Win32) Command Prompt`
3. Verify that `cl` command works
4. Generate with `cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" ...`

Answer (score 0):

Below changes worked fine for me:

1. Set the path in PATH : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin
2. Clear cmake cache
3. cmake --help

   > The following generators are available on this platform:
   >
   > Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
   >                              Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
   >
   > Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
   >                              Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
   >
   > Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
   >                              Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
   >
   > Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
   >                              Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
   >
   > Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
   >                              Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
   >
   > Visual Studio 8 2005 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2005 project files.
   >                              Optional [arch] can be "Win64".
   >
   > Visual Studio 7 .NET 2003    = Generates Visual Studio .NET 2003 project
   >                              files.
   >
   > Visual Studio 7 = Deprecated.  Generates Visual Studio .NET
   >                              2002 project files.
   >
   > Visual Studio 6 = Deprecated.  Generates Visual Studio 6

Used exactly same as above list which was `Visual Studio 11 2012`

`cmake -G "Visual Studio 11 2012" ..\..\source && cmake-gui ..\..\source`

Built fine.

Comment: With CMake 3.8, Visual Studio 2017 community, and Win10 v1803, I did not have to make the PATH modification, just using `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" ..` was sufficient!