# Running cmake in a different build directory on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake

I run CMake using `cmake ..` in order to make it output all the generated files in a different directory. This runs fine on Ubuntu, but breaks on Windows 10 when I try to run it. Running `cmake .` from the root project directory seems to work fine on both platforms. The output of `cmake ..` on Windows is:

```
PS D:\Development\cpp\hello-vulkan\build> cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0 to target Windows 10.0.17134.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The CMakeLists.txt is specified here:

```
include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(hello_vulkan)

# Download and setup GLFW
set(GLFW_DIR        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/glfw)
set(GLFW_BINARY_DIR ${GLFW_DIR}/bin)
ExternalProject_Add(
    glfw
    PREFIX         ${GLFW_DIR}
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
    GIT_TAG        3.2.1
    INSTALL_DIR    ${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}
    CMAKE_ARGS     -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}
)

# Link Vulkan and GLFW
set(VULKAN_DIR      ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/vulkan)
include_directories(${VULKAN_DIR}/include)
link_directories(
    ${VULKAN_DIR}/lib
    ${GLFW_BINARY_DIR}
)

# Setup project
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD             17)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH         ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/)
set(SOURCES                        source/main.cpp)

add_executable(hello_vulkan ${SOURCES})
add_dependencies(hello_vulkan glfw)
```

Any ideas what to do for it to work when running from a different directory on Windows?

Edit:
Here is the output from `cmake ..` on Ubuntu:

```
cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /mnt/d/Development/cpp/hello-vulkan/build
```

Comment: Hi bartlomiej.n, this looks quite surprising, could you also include the output from ``cmake .`` run from source dir, and check whether you indeed mentioned all cmake file in you questions?

Comment: Otherwise, possible problems on Windows usually come from whitespaces in the folder names (e.g. "Program Files"), so you might want to quote all your paths, though I don't see why this would not happen with ``cmake .``...

Comment: Yes, I included the whole `CMakeLists.txt` file here. There's not much more in the project really except for that - a "hello world" `main.cpp` file and Vulkan headers/libraries in the `lib` folder the project. There is no whitespace in folder names anywhere. C/C++ compilers are recognized without a problem on `cmake .`. I'll provide the output of this command later today on both platforms once I get back from work.

Comment: did you make any progress on this issue? I'm curious about what could cause this...

Comment: I'm working on it. Provided output from working `cmake ..` on Ubuntu above. What makes this case even weirder is that i moved up from the root project directory to its parent, created a test directory and ran `cmake ..\hello-vulkan` from there on Windows... and everything succeeded.

Comment: did you try forcing the compiler? you can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235601/cmake-the-c-compiler-identification-is-unknown)

Comment: @Silmathoron Forcing the generator to `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" ..` seems to work. Thank you! No idea why does this happen just for this directory. It's completely empty :)

Comment: Ok, it seems that something must've been changed in the meantime, since it works even without forcing the compiler now. No idea, but it seems to work without specifying the generator now

Comment: Mhh, this sounds like an outdated cmake cache that you forgot to clear ^^

Comment: That is entirely possible :)